# Error with EmbeddedId when invoking refresh method (Spring + JPA 2 hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having errors when invoking refresh method. I have the following tables: Ontology, Publication and ontology_by_publication.

This is ontology's pk: ontology_id | auto-increment
This is publication's pk: publication_id | auto-increment
This is ontology_by_publication pk: publication_publication_id, ontology_ontology_id, ontology_by_publication_id

The column ontology_by_publication_id has auto-increment set.

My OntologyByPublication looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ontology_by_publication")
public class OntologyByPublication implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7427863218422284148L;

@EmbeddedId
private OntologyByPublicationId ontologyByPublicationId;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "current_price")
private Double currentPrice;

@MapsId(value = "ontologyId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ontology_ontology_id")
private Ontology ontology;

@MapsId(value = "publicationId")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "publication_publication_id")
private Publication publication;

getters - setters
```

This is the @Embeddable Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class OntologyByPublicationId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ontology_by_publication_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ontologyByPubId;

    @Column(name = "publication_publication_id")
    private Long publicationId;

    @Column(name = "ontology_ontology_id")
    private Integer ontologyId;
```

I invoke the method below for persisting an OntologyByPublication object:

```
public OntologyByPublication saveOntologyByPublicationRefresh(
            OntologyByPublication ontologyByPublication) {
        try
        {
            em.persist(ontologyByPublication);
            em.flush();
            em.refresh(ontologyByPublication);

            return ontologyByPublication;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When the line containing em.refresh gets executed, this exception is thrown:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [org.springtest.mavenspringapp.domain.OntologyByPublication#org.springtest.mavenspringapp.domain.OntologyByPublicationId@73ba7b18]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: If you enable sql on console, you will see if the hibernate is able to save he object into the DB after you do the persist. Also check the DB if it is saving at the same time.

Comment: I would prefer you do em.merge(object) than persist, is this a new object that you are trying to save?

Comment: @Zeus yes it is a new object.. I'm using debug on server to see what's happening

Comment: So, on debug, do you see the object being saved? like the insert statement on the hibernate logs? Also, do you see the row saved in the DB?

Comment: Yes I can see an insert statement, everything goes well until the refresh method is invoked. When this happens, hibernate shows that it tries to execute a select statement, but an exception occurs, the exception EntityNotFound. Even though insertion occurs, when I check the database there are no records in the table.

Comment: I understand that the data is not yet commited to the DB. try to commit on the em and then refresh.

Comment: em.flush() commits to database but it won't persist.